# How can I set a variable from a text file's content in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I know how to use cat file

```
cat file.txt
```

but I have variable

```
[string]$body = "Body message here"
```

I need help changing it to get the text content from `file.txt`

I tried, but it didn't work.

```
  [string]$body = $cat file.txt
```

Here is full script, I am trying to change `param` section.

```
param 
(        
    [string]$email = $(read-host "Enter a recipient email"),
    [string]$subject = $(read-host "Enter the subject header"), 
    [string]$body = $(read-host "Enter the email text (optional)")
)
```

to

```
param 
(        
    [string]$email = "my@email.com",
    [string]$subject = "server", 
    [string]$body = gc C:\Users\myuser\Documents\somefolder\GnuWin32\bin\status.txt
)

# ==========================================================================
#   Functions
# ==========================================================================

function Send-Email
(
    [string]$recipientEmail = $(Throw "At least one recipient email is required!"), 
    [string]$subject = $(Throw "An email subject header is required!"), 
    [string]$body
)
{
    $outlook = New-Object -comObject  Outlook.Application 
    $mail = $outlook.CreateItem(0) 
    $mail.Recipients.Add($recipientEmail) 
    $mail.Subject = $subject 
    $mail.Body = $body

    # For HTML encoded emails 
    # $mail.HTMLBody = "<HTML><HEAD>Text<B>BOLD</B>  <span style='color:#E36C0A'>Color Text</span></HEAD></HTML>"

    # To send an attachment 
    # $mail.Attachments.Add("C:\Temp\Test.txt") 

    $mail.Send() 
    Write-Host "Email sent!"
}

Write-Host "Starting Send-MailViaOutlook Script."

# Send email using Outlook
Send-Email -recipientEmail $email -subject $subject -body $body

Write-Host "Closing Send-MailViaOutlook Script."
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
[string]$body = ( gc C:\Users\myuser\Documents\somefolder\GnuWin32\bin\status.txt )
```

note the brackets.

Comment: @Mowgli Glad to help! Next time post the error powershell give you too, it helps us to give answers

Comment: I wanted to do that myself too but I didn't know how to pause PS script. I am 2 days old to it.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following

```
[string]$body = gc file.txt
```

The command `gc` is an alias for `Get-Content` which will get the content of the specified item and return it as a `string`

**EDIT**

As `C.B.` pointed out, in your example you are trying to use `$cat` instead of `cat`.  `$cat` attempts to refer to a variable which isn't defined but `cat` is another alias for `Get-Content`

**EDIT2**

It looks like you are trying to initialize a param.  If so you need to do the following

```
[string]$body = $(gc "C:\Users\myuser\Documents\somefolder\GnuWin32\bin\status.txt")
```

Comment: Also `cat` is an alias for `get-content`, in the OP code the error is `$cat file.txt` where `$cat` is a non-existing variable and not the alias for `get-content cmdlet`.

Comment: get-content is also aliased to cat, so he can keep that.  Just need to lose the $.

Comment: I tried `gc` also, but it didn't work. Please see updated code in my question, in my other script `cat file.txt` worked. I don't know why it doesn't work here.

Comment: I tried all, `cat file.txt` also `cat "file.txt"` also `cat "c:\fullpath\file.txt"` none working.

Comment: @Mowgli are you sure the file exists then?  If the sample I wrote doesn't work then the most likeuly cause is the file not existing

Comment: @Mowgli i just saw that you are trying to init a param.  That is slightly different because of param init syntax, updated my answer